# Why is data not passed through my segue in my code?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to pass data via segue to the destination `ViewController` as a `UICollectionViewCell` is pressed using a protocol `cellWasPressed()`.
The `UICollectionView` is embedded in a `UITableViewCell` hence making it the delegate for the collection view.

I have tried the following code to get it to do the task but unfortunately the event data is not being passed via the segue hence the destinantion `ViewController` is empty.

Here is the delegate code found in the `UITableViewCell`:

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedIndex = indexPath
        selectedIndex2 = self.indexPath
        print(selectedIndex)
        print(selectedIndex2)
        delegate?.cellWasPressed()
    }
 protocol CellDelegate {
    func cellWasPressed()
 }

 extension UIResponder {
    func next<T: UIResponder>(_ type: T.Type) -> T? {
        return next as? T ?? next?.next(type)
    }
 }

 extension UITableViewCell {

    var TableView: UITableView? {
        return next(UITableView.self)
    }

    var indexPath: IndexPath? {
        return TableView?.indexPath(for: self)
    }
 }
```

& here is the code to prepare for the segue in the `BrowseViewController`:

```
 func cellWasPressed() {
        if let index = selectedIndex{
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ViewEventDetails", sender: index)
        }
    }
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   if(segue.identifier == "ViewEventDetails") {
            let destination = segue.destination as? EventDetailViewController
            if let index = sender as? IndexPath {

                if let index2 = selectedIndex2 {
                    let cell = EventTable.cellForRow(at: index2) as! PopularCell
                    let events = groupedEventArray[index2.row].1
                    let eventToPass = events[index.row]
                    destination?.navigationItem.title = eventToPass.event_name
                }

            }
        }
 }
```

I wish to fix this code in other for it to pass the event data to the destination `ViewController` via the segue.

Comment: your `indexPath` is definitely `nil` all the times – you are trying to collect the index-path from a table-view instance which is not remotely related to your table-cell-view.

Comment: *"unfortunately the event data is not being passed via the segue"* --- Do you mean the segue isn't happening? Do you mean the segue happens, but `EventDetailViewController`'s `navigationItem.title` doesn't show the data it got? Do you mean `eventToPass.event_name` is empty?

Comment: Yes the segues happens but the `navigationItem.title` is empty hence meaning the event data is not passed

Comment: First thing to do - change `destination?.navigationItem.title = eventToPass.event_name` to `destination?.navigationItem.title = "Test"` and see if the title shows up. If so, then your problem is with getting your data from your array(s). If not, then that line is not being executed -- meaning one of the `let` conditions is failing.

Comment: Yes I think the let condition is failing .. That's why I made it `if let`

Comment: @Carl - OK -- then set a breakpoint and step through your code, inspecting the variables / properties to find out which `if let` condition is failing, and why.

Comment: `if let index = sender as? IndexPath`